# Datorama - discover reports replacement

Tags: marketing-cloud, datorama, sfmc-datorama

Im working on transitioning the existing custom discover reports that are scheduled in multiple BU's.
We send reporting states based on key Email KPI's and this is sent to multiple users in various reports and ingested into other reporting tools.

When using the build report function I cant see a way to view and modify the look or order of the report, like I could do with the old reports interface. Some users request very specific build/groupings for their reports. Having to run a report and wait for an email to see what it looks like is time-consuming.

Does anyone know how to replicate the same experience in Datorama I can't see any documentation on how this can be achieved? Any advice or guidance/tips on this welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Measurement and Dimension area, you can drag those in any order you want

you can also click on the 'Run Now' Button to run the report and download it to see what it looks like, without emailing it

[image]